# Перенос субдоменов на внутренний каталог основного домена

Tags: wordpress

Я администрирую сайт graffcom.ru и у него есть 3 суб домена shop shild и table они все привязаны в меню 2 уровня (все на WordPress), и мне нужно shild и table перенести в корень к основному домену и соответственно сделать внутренними каталогами (graffcom.ru/shild, graffcom.ru/table). 
[image: Все сайты залиты на хостинге и каждый имеет свое доменное имя со своим IP]

 с точки зрения SEO это не комфортно 
Я нашел такую статью 
https://azbuka-wp.ru/perenos-sajta-v-kornevoj-domen/ 
Но при прописки домена в wp-config как мне правильно прописать, если у меня 2 субдомена которые нужно втыкать 
И нужно ли выносить весь корень вместе с graffcomru, table и shild и перезаливать их заново или все же поочередно кидать их в корень с последующим измением в wp-config и куда кидать конкретно -_- 
Пробовал плагины с автомиграцией что то не очень все получилось, всем добра))

Comment: Для начала напиши в вопросе как реализованы поддомены - отдельные сайты (если так, то какогво физ. расположение файлов) или мультисайт или как-то ещё? Заодно и запятые-точки расставь, чтобы было понятно что где.

Comment: А ту статью выкинь - читай правильные мануалы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по добавленному скрину это 4 отдельных сайта.

Если это так, то в "дочерних" сайтах достаточно в настройках заменить адреса, пройдясь плагином https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ или аналогичным.

Например :

```
/shop.graffcom.ru/
```

Заменить на

```
/graffcom.ru/shop/
```

И ничего в конфиге прописывать не надо.

Обязательно убедиться, что нигде старых адресов не осталось и не забывать про бекапы.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но что делать с IP, для поисковиков они также будут оставаться теми же сайтами

Comment: Не теми же самыми, а уже в подкаталогах. Т.е. для ПСов это уже  будет один сайт. И причём тут IP вообще.. Естественно он один на сайт. И если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решенным. Но только если помог ;)

Comment: я отметил, но  пользователи рейтингом меньше 15 учитываются, но не показываются
"Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Comment: Надо нажать на большую серую галку, сделав ее зеленой - так вы отмечаете, что приняли ответ